# restful service for batch updates

Tags: rest

I have a webservice that we intend to use to approve transactions.

This is a batch process but we feel PUT is the most appropriate method but believe its should normally be reserved for an individual transaction.

SHOULD we persist with PUT for this process and pass payload similar to:

```
{
    "Transactions": [
        {
            "TxId": "gtx-32",
            "VendorUserId" "76",
            "Status": "A"
        },
        {
            "TxId": "gtx-76",
            "VendorUserId" "76",
            "Status": "D"
        }
    ]
}
```

the above would set TxId: gtx-32 to status A and TxId: gtx-76 to status D

we would then reply with json object(s) of those transactions with the updated status.

if any one transaction was requesting an update to an invalid status the response would simply have the 'old' status against the transaction (should we include an error message there?).

If PUT is not the right method to adopt here we would welcome suggestions to alternatives.

We are aware that this is really only a partial update of the record so not a true PUT however this is most definitely an update...

Comment: I can't link the specific piece of the docs, but I really like how Parse.com did batch operations in REST. CTRL+F "Batch Operations" on this page: https://parse.com/docs/rest

Answer (score 4):

The `PUT` verb is intended to mean "put this document here". Importantly, the URL of a `PUT` request is intended to be the location at which the document should be "stored", i.e. a `GET` on the URL would return the document last put there.

In your case, unless you're "uploading" your batch of information to a specific location and can think of your batch as a document of itself, `PUT` is probably not what you mean.

Instead, you should probably use the more generic `POST`, intended to be used to ask an existing resource to **process** the document contained in the request. The response then expresses the result of the processing action.

`POST` is probably the most generic verb in the HTTP protocol. "Process" can be anything you need it to be, so it's generally the best to choose when you don't find any of the other verbs reflect the activity you want to perform.